# bash upload to sftp and moving files. looping around

Tags: bash, loops, sftp

Im somewhat beginner in bash scripting. I have here part of script that uploades files to sftp server. Then it shoud move files to other directory.
Else echo info about no files in source_dir. Problem is that its not moving files and is looping back to sftp login after files are already uploaded.

```
cd /dest_dir/
    for file5 in *.test
            do
                if test -f $file5
                then
                    echo 'some text.'
                    ((
                      echo "
    cd /dest_dir/
    lcd /source_dir/
    mput *.test
    exit
                        "
                    ) | sftp "user"@"host")

                    sleep 3 
                    mv /source_dir/$file5 /source_dir/test/
                else
                    echo -e 'some text'
                fi
```

Comment: You are looping over `*.test` files. In every loop, you upload all `*.test` files, yet you move only single file (the `$file5`). That looks wrong. But that may not be the primary problem.

Comment: so i changed from mput *.test to put $file5. will test that in few. thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is normally no reason to check that the files you are looping over actually exist.  If a file could disappear between the `for` and the `test`, it could just as well disappear between the `test` and the `echo` instead, in which case you end up referring to a file which no longer exists anyway.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob   # bash-only feature
cd /dest_dir/
(#echo "cd /dest_dir/"  # no use, you already did above
echo "lcd /source_dir/"
for file in *.test; do
    echo put "$file"
done
echo "exit" ) | sftp "user"@"host"
mv *.test /source_dir/test/
```

This opens a single `scp` connection for all the files.  It has the distinct disadvantage that if one of the files fails for some reason, the script doesn't catch that.

Apart from the [`shopt -s nullglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob) this should be portable to Bourne shell in general.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for tips. I made it: with loging:

```
SFTP_HOST="host"
SFTP_LOGIN="USER"
cd /path/
mylog=/path/sftp_session_$(date "+%Y_%m_%d").log
echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - text" >> $mylog
let licz5=`ls|wc -l`
let jest_plik=0
for file5 in *.test
do
    if test -f /patch_source1/$file5
    then
        let jest_plik=1
        echo "$(date "+%H:%M:%S") - transfer pliku "$file5" na serwer "$SFTP_HOST >> $mylog
    fi

    if test -f /source_patch2/$file6
    then
        echo "$(date "+%H:%M:%S") - transfer pliku "$file6" na serwer "$SFTP_HOST >> $mylog
    fi

    if test -f /source_patch3/$file7
    then
        echo "$(date "+%H:%M:%S") - transfer pliku "$file7" na serwer "$SFTP_HOST >> $mylog
    fi

    if test -f /source_patch4/$file8
    then
        echo "$(date "+%H:%M:%S") - transfer pliku "$file8" na serwer "$SFTP_HOST >> $mylog
    fi
done
if test $jest_plik -eq 1
then
echo 'text.'
(echo 'cd /dest_dir/
lcd /source_p_1/
mput *.test
lcd /source_p_2/
mput *.test
lcd /source_p_3/
mput *.test
lcd /source_p_4/
mput *.test
exit') | sftp $SFTP_LOGIN@$SFTP_HOST
echo "$(date "+%H:%M:%S") - send ok." >> $mylog
else
echo -e 'text'
fi
```